# ERROR 500 on axios API Call in Next JS after deployment to Vercel

Tags: deployment, next.js, axios, nodemailer, vercel

I am using a simple API to send Emails via axios and nodemailer in Next JS.
Locally everythings works normally, after deployment to Vercel i am getting Error 500 when trying to send an Email.

This is from the Form Component:

```
    async function onSubmitForm(values) {
        setLoading(true);
        let config = {
            method: "post",
            url: `${env.process.NEXT_LINK}/api/contact`,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            data: values,
        };
    
        try {
            const response = await axios(config);
            setLoading(false);
            setSuccess(true);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("frontend error", err);
        }
    }
```

Getting this Error in Dev Tools:

```
frontend error 
o {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
message
: 
"Request failed with status code 500"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response
: 
{data: '', status: 500, statusText: '', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Error
```

The contact API File:

```
import handlebars from "handlebars";
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

export default async (req, res) => {
    const { firstName, name, email, message, phone } = req.body;

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: process.env.NEXT_USER,
            pass: process.env.NEXT_GMAIL,
        },
    });

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // verify connection configuration
        transporter.verify(function (error, success) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                reject(error);
            } else {
                console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
                resolve(success);
            }
        });
    });

    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../../../../components/form/html/template.html");
    const source = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf-8").toString();
    const template = handlebars.compile(source);
    const replacements = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        message: message,
    };
    const htmlToSend = template(replacements);

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!firstName) {
            try {
                const emailRes = transporter.sendMail({
                    from: email,
                    to: {process.env.NEXT_MYEMAIL},
                    subject: `Email von ${name}`,
                    html: htmlToSend,
                });

                console.log("Message Sent", emailRes.messageId);
                res.status(200).json(req.body);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("GEHT NET", err);
            }
        } else {
            res.status(403).json(req.body);
        }
    });

    console.log(req.body, "Test");
};
```

Package JSON:

```
{
  "name": "default_next",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "export": "next build && next export",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@amir04lm26/react-modern-calendar-date-picker": "^1.0.1",
    "@palmabit/react-cookie-law": "^0.7.0",
    "@portabletext/react": "^1.0.6",
    "@sanity/asset-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "@sanity/client": "^3.3.2",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "framer-motion": "^7.1.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "next-sanity-image": "^3.2.1",
    "next-useragent": "^2.8.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.8",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-animate-on-scroll": "^2.1.5",
    "react-collapsed": "^3.3.2",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^8.0.1",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.34.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.3.3",
    "react-modern-calendar-datepicker": "^3.1.6",
    "react-spring": "^9.4.5",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.3",
    "react-use-scroll-snap": "0.0.4",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "swiper": "^8.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "eslint": "8.17.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

I declared all env variables in Vercel.

The Error logs in the Component File, but the path to the API is correct.

I tried hardcoding the Api path, checking all the env variables on Vercel, changing the path to see the Error Message (Error 404).

Ran it again locally, everything works there.

Comment: What error do you see in Vercel's [function logs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/logs#function-logs)?

Comment: Checked it out and got an error fo the handlebars html template file.
Removed handlebars and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

I looked into the Vercel functions logs and got an error for the handlebars template file. File not found. Removed handlebars from API and it worked!